# codeigniter undefined variable and invalid argument supplied for foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined

so i'm having this problem all the time and I still can't figure out what the problem really is. Can anyone help me with this?

my model:

```
 public function get_student(){
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_student');

    return $query->result();
}
```

my controller:

```
 public function view_list(){
    $this->load->model('student_view_model');

    $data['results'] = $this->student_view_model->get_student();

    $this->load->view('view_student_list', $data);

}
```

my view:

```
    <?php foreach($results as $row) { ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->student_fname ; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->student_course ; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->student_company ; ?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>
```

my error:

```
   A PHP Error was encountered

   Severity: Notice

   Message: Undefined variable: results

   Filename: views/view_student_list.php

   Line Number: 26


   A PHP Error was encountered

   Severity: Warning

   Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

   Filename: views/view_student_list.php

   Line Number: 26
```

my question is why does my variable $results undefined? I just copied it from my previous code and my previous code works and this one doesn't.

Comment: Try changing the return `$query->result();` on model to return `$query->result_array();`

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what `data['results']` actually is?

Comment: Try `<td><?php echo $row['student_fname'] ; ?></td>`

Comment: nothing happens. still the same.

Comment: If you are using the latest version of codeIgniter then you have to first declare the variable before using it just like we do in JAVA. So in your CONTROLLER Method declare `$data=array();` at the beginnning

Comment: if I use print_r, it only displays "1".